# How to keep the inline box to show, when it contains no content?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a inline box of SPAN. even i style it with inline-block or width, it doesn't show when it contains no content. i have to add a non-break space to keep it to show.

```
<span class='myClass'>&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving it a height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a inline box of SPAN. even i
>   style it with inline-block or width,
>   it doesn't show when it contains no
>   content.

[Here is the working demo](http://jsbin.com/odime3)

**CSS Used:**

```
  .myClass{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Span doesn't have any formatting of it's own, it simply tells the browser to apply the style rules to whatever is within the <span>, so if it's empty it won't show.  Use <div> if you want a box container that will always show.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it a height: http://jsfiddle.net/Fx8TB/

```
<p>asdf<span></span>adsf</p>
<p>asdf<span id=withHeight></span>adsf</p>
```

.

```
span
{
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}

#withHeight
{
    height:10px;
}
```